# The first semi-official public use of Campfire?

Tags: discussion

> **Transcript**
>
> You can now access a summarized transcript on the blog at https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-overflow-funding-chat-qa-transcript/

**Campfire Room**: https://stackoverflow.campfirenow.com/room/297336

@Spolsky sent out [a tweet](http://twitter.com/spolsky/status/13378100615) inviting his followers to participate in a quick chat regarding the VC situation. This appears to be the first public semi-official use of Campfire by the SO team. Notable guests were:

1. [Joel Spolsky](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky)
2. [Brent Ozar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/26837/brent-ozar)
3. [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)
4. [Geoff Dalgas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas)

Is this a sign of some sort - is SO publicly acknowledge an adoption of Chat-style communication with the community, or was this merely a unique occurrence.

Another question would be whether *you* were able to make it, and what *you* thought of the experience? Was it too busy, too loose, very informative, comfortable?

Comment: I stopped following Joel because all he said was "jam"

Comment: $10 Welbog is going to claim IRC is better than Campfire!

Comment: @ivo http://twitter.com/BrentO/status/13381087553

Comment: Meh. Without all the blather, doesn't really give much of an idea of how CF would work in The Real World...

Comment: How does one create an account there? I have only the option to sign in with an existing account.

Comment: @Ivo Smoke signals are better than Campfire.

Answer (score 2):

I watched it for a little while - it was pretty chaotic. I was mainly interested in the team's replies to people's questions. It would be nice if someone could post a transcript of the conversation so I can read it later - the scrollback appears to only go so far. It might have been better if Joel set up a Stack Exchange for questions about the deal and answered them that way.

Comment: yeah I didn't think this was planned well. Just MHO. Not the way I would have done it.

Comment: It was on topic for a while...but now it's a bit deviated.

Comment: A chat with more than 3 people always results in chaotic

Answer (score 1):

I get kicked out of the room

Comment: Are you "Jeff Atwood"? Somebody kept trying to occupy that name. As a result, the room was locked (no more occupants permitted).

Comment: If I were Jeff Atwood, I wouldn't be here. I'd take the $6M and head to the Bahamas

Comment: Is this supposed to be a public thing?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a preview of how things will work on stackexchange 2.0?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. This event uses a medium that SE2.0 will also (possibly) use, but it doesn't necessarily follow that the results will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I quite enjoyed the chat, but as usual when a lot of people chat, the signal-to-noise ratio was very low. Someone mentioned that (possible) future chats should use OpenID to identift SO users, and I think that would be a great idea.